# In-app Purchase auto renewable

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm making an iPhone app that completes a PC application.
I sync my iphone application with webservice to the PC application, making it thus an extension.
I wanted to sell it for periods of time. (Example 1 month, 6 months, 1 year).

For such applications the Apple allows use in-app purshase  auto-renewable?

If yes, can someone indicate me a good tuturial of how to implement this in-app?
I already implemented consomable and non-consumable in-app previously.
I've read this tutorial among others:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation

But still could not find any on in-app auto-renewable.
A code example also serves

if this type of in-app which does not serve advise?

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680059/auto-renewable-subscription-in-ios7/45220204#45220204
might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will answer, but auto-renewable in-app purchase are allowed **only** if your app provide new content each time (or often) the user pays. (like provide new magazine, video...)

If your purpose is to do a premium subscription which give access to so premium functions (so no logic of periodical new content), Apple will reject your app.

You will find much more explanations on the subject here: [The limited world of auto-renewable subscriptions](http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions)

Comment: then how I can make a premium subscription? 
my idea was that the user without paying the monthly fee is not got passed the login. 
in-app purshase Comsumible or Non-Renewing Subscription?

Comment: Just do a consumable. Non-renewable subscription brings no advantage. (It just gives the user the possibility to renew at the same price) In the end it's the same than do a one-shot consumable.