# What kind of In-App purchase should I use?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, icloud, auto-renewing, non-renewing-subscription

In my app, I would like users to buy a subscription for Backup, Sync, and more.

so I found out that Apple offer two kinds of subscription IAP:

- Non Renewable Subscription
- Auto Renewable Subscription

which should I use, given that I don't have a server, and I rely on iCloud for the sync?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In-app Purchase auto renewable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755188/in-app-purchase-auto-renewable)

Answer (score 2):

Auto-renewable in-app purchase are allowed **only** if your app provide new content each time (or often) the user pays. (like provide new magazine, video...)

If your purpose is to do a premium subscription which give access to so premium functions (so no logic of periodical new content), Apple will reject your app.

You will find much more explanations on the subject here: [The limited world of auto-renewable subscriptions](http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this, but I think it is quite difficult to get Apple to accept an auto-renewable subscription for anything but Newsstand apps. For other use cases, I think they prefer you to adopt the non-renewable subscription.

You could also consider a one time payment to 'unlock' the feature, rather than a subscription, since you aren't actually paying any ongoing costs (e.g. storing data).